# Implementing Automation for Functional Testing from scratch - Selenium, Python, PyTest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, pytest

I am currently a manual tester for a very large and complex application (there is no automation testing at all).

Currently I am solo working on automating everything with selenium. It is my initiative, and there is no one above me, more experienced or someone I could consult this with. I am also not experienced with automated testing - I am pretty comfortable with Python, Selenium.

It's a very large app, and often times just to finish one test-case, I would have to fill out multiple forms and progress through the app to reach the specific part.

Now I can automate all this form filling and general workflow, but this would be only half of the job, so my question is (apart from a lot of other questions such as how to properly design it etc., and I am open for discussion) is - could I also use pytest for full automation?

Thing is, the application is being developed by another company, and they only send us test cases with prerequisites and expected results.

So without real experience, I can't see how would I fully test this with pytest.

Would I need more technical test-cases so that I could check the elements with pytest perhaps? (Maybe something I could discuss with the company)

Or if pytest would not be possible, could you perhaps share other ways of doing this? I am thinking maybe record the process and then just check the video?

Thanks

Comment: It seems strange that another company is developing the site and yet they expect you, a non-employee to test it???

Comment: We are talking huge corporation with complicated structure. I am very new at this job, so still figuring it out. I am pretty sure developing company has its own tests, we just do functional tests.

Answer (score 0):

pytest should be able to handle the automation you are trying to do. Some suggestions:

1. Create one test per test case.
2. Each test case creates a browser instance, completes the test case steps, validates the outcome, and closes the browser. This limits the affect separate runs can have on each other.
3. Set up your tests to run in parallel. You should be able to run at least 4 browsers at once on a single machine, maybe more depending on the processor.
4. Investigate and use the page object model. The concept is that you create one class (page object) per page. The page object should contain the locators for only that page and have methods to take care of each of the actions a user would do on the page.
5. Build one test at a time. Start writing the test and as you navigate to a page, create the page object if it doesn't already exist. Add the locators and methods needed for that test. Don't spend time creating locators or methods for future tests or for other actions that a user *might* do on the page. That will save you time by focusing on completing only what's needed for that one test.

As you write each page object, try to write reusable methods, e.g. if there's a dropdown, don't write a method for each OPTION in the dropdown, instead have a parameter passed in for the OPTION value that the method uses to make a selection.

Hopefully this will give you a head start. I'll try to write a simple test and page object so you can get a better idea.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for taking the time. I am currently studying how to properly structure Page Object Model in order to make the code as clear, flexible and maintainable as possible. Things is, I am still pretty new and don't know the app that well myself - I know though that it's very complex - each test can go through multiple user roles and steps. This is the first bigger challenge - now I heard something about pytest fixtures, would this be a use-case for them? Another thing, tests I have seen so far were something like "Do this, this, this.. then check if question is present here"

Comment: So with test like this, how can I target that specific part with pytest? Do I need to know element locator? Maybe that would only complicate things for such a huge app. Or should  test-cases come differently so as to connect them with pytest? Maybe I could ask for this. It's all open, I can do pretty much anything I want, but I am trying to understand it well first. I will need some time to understand the app properly as well.

Comment: Another things as you mention in step 5, I am building the way that choices are handled as arguments - but the problem is that it would be crazy amount of forms to fill each time - can this be again predefined somehow before? Like to have some templates. Maybe above mentioned fixtures do this, but need to study more on that

Comment: I'm assuming that if the company that is providing you the test cases had an automation team, they would be writing the automation so I would assume that you are going to have to write all of this yourself, including locators, etc. Hopefully if you get this started and show it's value, your company will bring more people on the task to help and you will be the beginnings of an automation team.

Comment: I found [an article](https://medium.com/@zeitdeuter/page-object-models-implementation-with-pytest-b9673744b8c0) describing POM with some [sample code](https://github.com/aifakhri/web-app-testing-framework-example) that should help. This is only an example... I would put one test per .py file to make them easier to find and edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will go through the example. And yes indeed, I am writing it all myself, locators, POM, automating the whole workflow. I just can't see yet, due to lack of experience, how to transform current test cases into full automation. Part of that is complexity of the app as well as my current lower understanding of it. It is very possible this would be a start of an automation team, and that's why I am thinking about how to design this properly.